# How do I use Numpy percentiles with Pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi all out of curiosity as the title says let's just say the hypothetical situation I want to used numpy percentiles on Pandas dataframe due to having a large amount of data and I herd it is more computationally efficient. I then want to transform the time to datetime with

```
df['SP2_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(((df['SP2_datetime_in_sec'])), unit='s')
```

after I filter out the 90% percentile data since overally I want to overlay a scatter plot of these values over the minutely data I have.

```
        import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        df = pd.read_csv('data.tsv',
            sep='\t', usecols=['SP2_datetime_in_sec', 'data'], encoding='utf-8-sig', index_col=False, dtype=np.float64)
        df = np.percentile(df['data'],90)
#step to transform date into a readable format as started abouv        
df.to_csv(
            '90quantile_data.tsv',
            sep='\t')
```

I get AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: The numpy documentation says that percentile returns a single scalar value, which is not a dataframe.

Comment: It sounds like you want to filter/keep the values below the 90% percentile. You can calculate the value with `np.percentile()` and  then do a check in your dataframe for which values are above/below that value and keep only said rows.